# Python "distance/time/fuel calculator" help #2

Tags: python, calculator

I have a working program that asks *how far in kilometers I want to travel* (among a few more questions) and calculate *how long my travel will last* and *how much fuel i will burn* - according to the information I gave as input.

Now - I want to make the option of *inserting time INSTEAD of distance* be available in the program, too so that I can say *how many minutes I wanna drive at a certain speed* (instead of how many kilometers) and the program will calculate and print - this time - *the distance traveled according to all the input...*

With all this being said, I think the code itself will probably explain what I mean the best:

1. Here is the working code so far with only the "distance" input:

```
while True:

    # Get fuel remaining in the tank from the user
    fuel_tank = input("Enter fuel remaining:")
    fuel_tank = float(fuel_tank)

    # Get L/100km used from the user
    fuel = input("Enter car's L/100kmh:")
    fuel = float(fuel)

    # Get distance driven from the user
    distance = input("Enter kilometers driven:")
    distance = float(distance)

    # Get speed used from the user
    speed = input("Enter driving speed:")
    speed = float(speed)

    # Calculate and print the answer
    time = distance / speed
    fuel_burned = distance / 100 * fuel
    fuel_remaining = fuel_tank - fuel_burned

    hours = int(time)
    minutes_remainder = (time - hours) * 60
    minutes = int(minutes_remainder)


    print("-----------------------------------------")
    print("Time traveled: ", hours,"h:",minutes,"min")
    print("Fuel burned: ", fuel_burned," liters")
    print("==========================================")
    print("Fuel remaining: ", fuel_remaining," liters")
    print("==========================================")

    again = input("Go again? (y/n)")
    if again == "n":
        break
```

2. And here is my attempt at making the desired modification (which, of course, doesn't work):

```
while True:

    # Get fuel remaining in the tank from the user
    fuel_tank = input("Enter fuel remaining:")
    fuel_tank = float(fuel_tank)

    # Get L/100km used from the user
    fuel = input("Enter car's L/100kmh:")
    fuel = float(fuel)

    # Get distance driven from the user
    distance = input("Enter kilometers driven (type 0 to input time instead):")
    distance = float(distance)
    if distance == 0:
    pass    # pass here

    ### Get duration of the drive in minutes from the user
    minutes_remainder = input("Enter minutes driven (1h = 60min):")
    minutes_remainder = int(minutes_remainder)
    if distance != 0:
    pass    # pass here

    # Get speed used from the user
    speed = input("Enter driving speed (km/h):")
    speed = float(speed)

    # Calculate and print the answer
    time = distance / speed
    distance = time * speed
    fuel_burned = distance / 100 * fuel
    fuel_remaining = fuel_tank - fuel_burned

    ## Time format
    hours = int(time)
    minutes_remainder = (time - hours) * 60
    minutes = int(minutes_remainder)


    print("-----------------------------------------")
    print("Time traveled: ", hours,"h:",minutes,"min")
    print("Distance traveled: ", distance, "kilometers")
    print("Fuel burned: ", fuel_burned," liters")
    print("==========================================")
    print("Fuel remaining: ", fuel_remaining," liters")
    print("==========================================")

    again = input("Go again? (y/n)")
    if again == "n":
        break
```

So, anybody have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: Might it be easier to ask the user if they want the distance option or the time option? Your existing logic would go under part of an if/else switch on the input and your new code about calculating distance from time under the other part.

Comment: `pass` commands have be indented.